# Including libraries in Eclipse IDE with C++ - Best Practice

Tags: eclipse, include

For a recent set of projects I have used Eclipse, using MinGW as the compilation system.  I have needed to include two libraries for linear algebra:

> [TNT and JAMA/C++](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/download.html) 
>   [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)

JAMA/C++ comes as two directories of header files.  Armadillo requires both a directory of header files and some dll libraries.

I somehow got it working(!), but what is the best way to include these types of libraries within Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate source folders for them. That way they will be copied to the bin folder during builds yet can be easily managed.

Comment: Accepted this answer as no other...so still unsure if this is "best practice"!